# Why does Krishna accept Gandhari's curse?

Tags: krishna, gandhari

Krishna was not responsible for the death of the Kauravas.

Why does Krishna accept Gandhari's curse?

Comment: I think one doesn't get a choice to accept or reject a curse, It is implied on the cursed one forcefully, though Krishna was the supreme god and had the power to reject the curse he didn't choose to do so, as the Yadavs of his clan did not participate in the holy war (Dharma Yudh) and had to be punished for that. (There could be no by-standers in a holy war)

Comment: @V.Aggarwal it seems many Yadavs did fight...https://www.quora.com/Why-didn%E2%80%99t-Yadavas-participate-in-the-Kurukshetra-War?share=1

Answer (score 8):

## Why Shree Krishna accepted Gandhari's Curse?

There are several  verses in Mahabharata  which are explaining the reasons why Shree Krishna accepted Gandharis curse. Lets see them.

After the kurukshetra war was over and the the ladies of race of kuru visited battlefield and there they saw the dead bodies of all their loved ones. They started  moaning after that in great grief. Gandhari at that time  burning with grief complained and expressed her objections towards Shree Krishna of  not stopping this great war and massacre  even he was capable of doing so. She accused Shree Krisha being indifferent to Kauravas and Pandavas. As mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11024.htm) - Stri Parva- Chapter 25.

> O Janardana, why wert thou indifferent to them? Thou wert competent to
>   prevent the slaughter, for thou hast a large number of followers and a
>   vast force. Thou hadst eloquence, and thou hadst the power (for
>   bringing about peace). Since deliberately, O slayer of Madhu, thou
>   wert indifferent to this universal carnage, therefore, O mighty-armed
>   one, thou shouldst reap the fruit of this act. By the little merit I
>   have acquired through waiting dutifully on my husband, by that merit
>   so difficult to attain, I shall curse thee, O wielder of the discus
>   and the mace! Since thou wert indifferent to the Kurus and the
>   Pandavas whilst they slew each other, therefore, O Govinda, thou shalt
>   be the slayer of thy own kinsmen! In the thirty-sixth year from this,
>   O slayer of Madhu, thou shalt, after causing the slaughter of thy
>   kinsmen and friends and sons, perish by disgusting means in the
>   wilderness. The ladies of thy race, deprived of sons, kinsmen, and
>   friends, shall weep and cry even as these ladies of the Bharata race!

---

Now Shree Krishna already was aware  that this curse incident will going to happen .It is according to his will and divine plan this incident of curse by gandhari took place at first place. Shree Krishna after gandhari gave him the curse said to her that he is well aware about the events that were going to happen in the future and Gandhari by giving him the curse aided him in the accomplishment of that task of exterminating the race of Yadavas , the task which was impossible even for humans , gods and demons as said by Krishna. In the same chapter verse 48

> जानेsमेतदप्येवं चीर्ण चरसि क्षत्रिये |
>  दैवादेव विनश्यन्ति वृष्णयो
>   नात्र संशय : ||48 ||
>
> There is none in the world, save myself, that is capable of
>   exterminating the Vrishnis. **I know this well.** I am endeavouring to
>   bring it about. In uttering this curse, O thou of excellent vows, **thou
>   hast aided me in the accomplishment of that task.** The Vrishnis are
>   incapable of being slain by others, be they human beings or gods or
>   Danavas. The Yadavas, therefore shall fall by one another’s hand.’

---

## To Respect Gandharis words

Shree Krishna was well capable of diverting this curse , but he did not do so , one of the reason is to respect Gandhari's curse and words and to make them true , which she uttered in anger. He incited the curse by asking Yadavas to make pilgrimage.  This is mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16002.htm) - Mausala Parva - Chapter 2

> इत्युक्त्वा वासुदेवस्तु चिकीर्षु: सत्यमेव तत् || 
> आज्ञापयामास तदा
>   तिर्थयात्रामरिंदम : ||23 ||
>
> Vasudeva, having said so, endeavoured **to bring about those
>   occurrences which would make Gandhari’s words true.**. That chastiser
>   of foes commanded the Vrishnis to make a pilgrimage to some sacred
>   water.

---

So Shree Krishna accepted Gandharis curse because - :

- Shree Krishna did't wanted to disrespect Gandhari  by averting the curse which she gave to Krishna by   merit which she acquired by tapas of dutifully following her  husband.
- It was the divine plane of exterminating the race of Yadavas by their own hands by Shree Krishna himself. Gandhari by cursing him just aided him in his plan. So he accepted the curse.

Comment: good answer. upvoted.@SwiftPushkar