# Can some one explain this painting of Fire God with people watching?

Tags: identification-request

Can some one explain this painting of Fire God with people watching? looks like a painting from 1500 AD. I found it in my home. can some one explain what is happening here?

[image: Can some one explain this painting Fire God with people watching? looks like 1500 AD must be in expensive.]

Comment: Amazing! But How did you figure out that this painting is from 1500AD?

Comment: Seems like the culmination of a yajna. Animals near his feet are probably the ones that were sacrificed. Compare with [this](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rYym9l9JhJ8/WBDxuOFy9QI/AAAAAAAAe1w/tz44J0S-06UONrvYS5NmiDRsMy5o8-3jACLcB/s640/Shree-Yagya-Bhjagwan-Ji.jpg) and [this](https://www.kamat.com/kalranga/mythology/ramayan/30014.jpg) from Ramayana.

Comment: This is definitely from the Mughal era or afterwards. Notice the cap-wearing men at the bottom-left.

Comment: Compare this with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishyasringa#/media/File:God_emerge_from_fire_give_food_to_Dasratha.jpg This is the episode where Rishyasringa brought rain to the people of Angadesa.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like it's telling an imposter story, as the painting draws you into the big figure in the middle, so you are distracted from the imposter with the bunny ears. The painting is probably trying to convey that you should not be distracted by big flashy stuff and pay attention to people in the background.

Impostor stories are common in Hinduism, so it could be referring to any or all of them. e.g. Yudhiṣṭhira being a Brāhmaṇa, Kali being Gabriel, Kṛṣṇa clearly having ulterior motives for appearing on Earth, the first human constantly pretending not to be a deity, etc.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs04006.htm

[Where is the verse(s) about Sāvarṇi (a name of the first human) in the Ṛgveda (Rig Veda)? Who are Sāvarṇya and Saraṇyū?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42995/where-is-the-verses-about-s%c4%81var%e1%b9%87i-a-name-of-the-first-human-in-the-%e1%b9%9agveda-r)

[Why does Krishna accept Gandhari's curse?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36491/why-does-krishna-accept-gandharis-curse)

Comment: Haha that was hilarious.

Comment: Can I ask lord Krishna's "ulterior motive" for appearing on Earth according to you ?