# Where is the verse(s) about Sāvarṇi (a name of the first human) in the Ṛgveda (Rig Veda)? Who are Sāvarṇya and Saraṇyū?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, human, manu

[image]

I tried control-f-ing to find the mention of Sāvarṇi but it did not work.

Comment: Extract is from http://sanskritdictionary.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rig Veda X.62.9,11 speak about  Sāvarṇya and Sāvarṇi.

> न तम॑श्नोति॒ कश्च॒न दि॒व इ॑व॒ सान्वा॒रभ॑म् । **सा॒व॒र्ण्यस्य॒** दक्षि॑णा॒
> वि सिन्धु॑रिव पप्रथे ॥९॥
>
> No one succeeds in taking hold of him any more than the back of
> heaven. The priestly gift of **Sāvarṇya** spreads out like a river
>
> स॒ह॒स्र॒दा ग्रा॑म॒णीर्मा रि॑ष॒न्मनु॒: सूर्ये॑णास्य॒ यत॑मानैतु॒
> दक्षि॑णा ।
> ***साव॑र्णेर्दे॒वाः*** प्र ति॑र॒न्त्वायु॒र्यस्मि॒न्नश्रा॑न्ता॒ अस॑नाम॒ वाज॑म् ॥११॥
>
> Let Manu, giver of thousands, leader of the horde, not suffer harm.
> Let his priestly gift come, aligning itself with the sun. Let the gods
> extend the lifetime of **Sāvarṇi**, under whose auspices we,
> unwearied, won the prize of victory.

---

Sāṁvaraṇi is found in the Rigveda in one passage, where it naturally seems to be a patronymic (‘descendant of Saṁvaraṇa’) of manu. (Rig Veda VIII.51.1)

> यथा॒ मनौ॒ ***सांव॑रणौ॒*** सोम॑मि॒न्द्रापि॑बः सु॒तम् । नीपा॑तिथौ
> मघव॒न्मेध्या॑तिथौ॒ पुष्टि॑गौ॒ श्रुष्टि॑गौ॒ सचा॑ ॥१॥
>
> Just as at **Manu Sāṃvaraṇi’s** you drank pressed soma, Indra, and at
> Nīpātithi’s, at Medhyātithi’s, (do so) at Puṣṭigu’s, at Śruṣṭigu’s,
> bounteous one.

[According to Bloomfield](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/sAMvaraNi/manu), it is a corruption for sāvarṇi, a reference to Manuऽs birth from the savarṇā, ‘similar’ female who was substituted for Saraṇyū according to the legend.