# Was Krsna ever wrong?

Tags: krishna, dharma

Was Krsna ever wrong? Can you give examples? I have not tried anything else to solve my problem. Why is that a problem? I am here to solve my problem. That is my question and I don’t have anything else to add to my question.

Was Krishna even a real human, or just a deva in the human form?

Comment: Krsna is beyond right and wrong. If you mean about his acts in avatar, then they all were right. Where there is Krsna, there is Dharma.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong" here? Does it mean adharma?

Comment: @LSSJBroly what does "beyond" even mean?  others cannot judge his action? whether of the present time or his own time?  and if one did judge him, would they automatically be wrong to judge Krnsa's action? i never understood that beyond business...

Comment: i vaguely recall a story where some person (a woman) puts a curse on Krsna condemning his whole village to death.  the cause for this curse can be thought in layman's terms to be the fruit of wrong behavior or wrong action.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36501/26679 This might help you

Comment: Here 'Beyond' means he is beyond the cycle of Karma. He is not captured in the noose of karma like us. But he chooses to bear the fruits of karma, whether good or bad, because he follows Dharma and tries to establish Dharma, like, for example he accepted Gandhari's curse.

Comment: so basically Krishna wanted to kill his own people and he felt bad about it so he needed the help of Gandhari?  i think that is fair enough...

Comment: @LSSJBroly or maybe like you said he wants to establish dharma while maintaining free choice among men.  he attempts to exemplify the consequences of choice and behavior.  man is free to choose but he must deal with the consequences.

Comment: It was destined that lord Krishna will kill his clan members. He was knowing that all sorts of things were going to happen and ultimately killing of his clan. So everything, including the curse, was part of destiny. It was possible for Lord Krishna to nullify the curse, but he did not do so because he wanted to establish dharma and hence was ready to bear the fruits of karma and hence he respected the curse

Comment: but was krnsa a human?  or only a deva in the human form? was he even living?  all living things are conditioned, no?  aren't all conditioned things subject to suffering?

Comment: @lilredindy you need to first undersfandthe concept of Ishwara. Ishwara is a special type of being, who is fully alive, but is not subject to karma. He is omnipresent, omnipotent, omniscient and omnibenevolent and he can, by definition, do noting bad, because the definition of good itself is derived from him. This Ishwara once in a while takes human form this is known as Avatar. It's the ultimate God taking a Human form and living amongst us. So instead of trying to understand the good and bad nature of Avataras, try to understand the nature of Ishwara.

Comment: @Optimus ok, no karma, and no dukkha?

Comment: @lilredindy yes, he has no dukka, but sometimes he acts as tho he has dukka for the sake of drama.

Comment: @LSSJBroly after reading the only answer posted to this question - an answer i accept - i would argue that he does not bear the fruits of karma.  he is not affected by karma, and thus no fruit (vipaka)...

Comment: I have already told earlier that he is not affected by Karma. Read carefully. You did not understand what I said so no point in arguing. Anyways, glad to know that you understood the concept and the answer helped you. Peace✌️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. There are no such examples because Krishna being the Supreme Self is always right.**

As per scriptures, where Krishna is there, that side undoubtedly is Dharma and righteousness (cf. Bhagvad Geeta - BG [18.78](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=78&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&choose=1)).

As says the Mahabharata -

> Verse 13.153.39b
>
> यतः कृष्णस्ततो धर्मो यतो धर्मस्ततो जयः ॥ ३९.ख ॥
>
> > - **Where Krishna is there, know that Dharma is verily there, and in Dharma lies Victory.**

Further,

Swami Sivananda of the Divine Life Society, in his book - *LORD KRISHNA, HIS LILAS AND TEACHINGS* says -

> #### [Introduction](https://www.dlshq.org/download/lord-krishna-his-lilas-and-teachings/): Lord Krishna – The Supreme Lord
>
> Though Lord Krishna appeared in human form, He had an Aprakritika,
> divine body. **He did not take any birth. He did not die. He appeared
> and disappeared through His Yoga Maya.** This is a secret, known only to
> His devotees, Yogis and sages.

So yes, Krishna was just playing the *leela* pasttime of being a human, for he was the god himself in human disguise.

One of the basic difference between an incarnation (*avatâra*) birth or manifestation, and a normal human's birth is, that while a human jeeva birth is not under the jeeva's control, governed by laws of Karma and causality.

On the other hand, an incarnation like Krishna or Sri Rama manifests out of their own volition (*sankalpa-shakti*).

**AND, thus Krishna is never wrong, for he's the God himself born to establish Dharma (cf. [BG 4.7-8](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=7&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&etradi=1&choose=1))**.